# Problems exporting basic pure JavaScript charts using Asp.Net handler

Tags: asp.net, fusioncharts

I am having difficulty exporting a pure JavaScript chart from the basic examples provided in the C# solution (demo package from fusion charts). My sample is from the evaluation code provided on the FusionChart website.

I have added

`exportenabled='1'  exportHandler='http://localhost:64162/CS/Export_Handler/FCExporter.aspx'`

to the existing Data.xml file in order to enable export using the local handler

Chart definition for the chart BasicExample/MultiChartsJS.aspx:

```
<chart caption='Monthly Unit Sales' xAxisName='Month' yAxisName='Units' showValues='0'
    formatNumberScale='0' showBorder='1' exportenabled='1' exportHandler='http://localhost:64162/CS/Export_Handler/FCExporter.aspx'>
    <set label='Jan' value='462' />
    <set label='Feb' value='857' />
    <set label='Mar' value='671' />
    <set label='Apr' value='494' />
    <set label='May' value='761' />
    <set label='Jun' value='960' />
    <set label='Jul' value='629' />
    <set label='Aug' value='622' />
    <set label='Sep' value='376' />
    <set label='Oct' value='494' />
    <set label='Nov' value='761' />
    <set label='Dec' value='960' />
</chart>
```

I am pointing the exportHandler to the C# export handler (FCExporter) found in the same solution.

When invoking the export, the handler fires, but I am encountering two different runtime errors in the handler:

Failures inside FCExporter.cs

1)Jpeg conversion:

```
gr.Clear(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" + rawImageData["bgcolor"].ToString()));
```

is failing because rawImageData["bgcolor"] already contains a #

2)PDF conversion

```
 int fRepeat = int.Parse(split_data[1]);
```

is failing with an out of range exception

It almost seems like the handler is out of sync with the charts that are being exported. It works if I point to the external fusion site for the export. Is there a new version of the handler available? I am using version 3.3.1-sr2.19840 of FusionCharts.js

Comment: Does the chart display correctly on the page? Also is this exactly the same markup that you use for exporting?

Comment: Yes, the chart renders correctly on the page (with the export icon). The issue is runtime errors inside the export handler. I basically just modified the chart xml for an existing chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using the export handler that is designed for exporting Flash charts only. For exporting JavaScript charts, you would need to setup export separately.

**The .NET export handler is not yet equipped to handle JavaScript charts.** Having said that, you are not out of luck yet. There are two options you still have:

1. Use pure server-side rendering to generate chart image - http://blog.fusioncharts.com/2013/03/how-to-save-charts-as-images-at-server-side/
2. Use the CodePlex SVG rendering engine for .NET after sending the chart's SVG data to server - http://svg.codeplex.com (You can get a chart's SVG string, even on IE, using `chartInstance.toSVGString()`)

> > Note that if you are using PHP export handler, it can handle both flash and javascript export using the same export handler as mentioned in the documentation article - http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/exporting-image/ECPureJS.html

Comment: I would add more options and maybe develop a sample and update the answer sometime soon.

Comment: I have got some sample codes that you can use to export within .NET. The code is not that polished and if you're interested, I can share them (if feasible, then here itself or as a downloadable item.)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following 2 attributes to your chart definition:

```
exportAtClient='0' exportAction='download'
```

This should make sure that export handler is being used.